# How to setState conditionally in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React SPA simulating John Conway's Game of Life. On initialisation/load the app needs to check the height and width of the .gridContainer element in order for it to know how many rows and columns to draw for the grid (*see Ref 1*). The problem is, the grid isn't initialising on load. However, for some strange reason does initialise if you click the 'Clear' button *twice*. Please view game-of-life-sage.vercel.app  and click 'Clear' twice'. - console logs included.

From console logging everything it seems the grid only initialises if the clearGrid function is called after numRows and numCols has been defined, which makes sense. How do I setGrid (*Ref 2 below*) only after numRows and numCols have been initialised without creating a 'React Hook "useState" is called conditionally' error? I can't put it in a useEffect with dependancies of numRows and numCols either as I get "React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback".

```
function App() {

let width;
let height;
let numRows;
let numCols;

// REF 1
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    let getGridSize = document.querySelector('.gridcontainer');
    width = getGridSize.offsetWidth
    height = getGridSize.offsetHeight

    let useableCols = (width / gridSize);
    let useableRows = (height / gridSize);
    numRows = Math.round(useableRows);
    numCols = Math.round(useableCols);
}

if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    console.log("numRows: ",numRows);
    console.log("numCols: ",numCols);
}

const clearGrid = () => {
    console.log("clearGrid called");
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        rows.push(Array.from(Array(numCols), () => 0))
    }
    return rows
}

// REF 2
const [grid, setGrid] = useState(() => {
    console.log("init grid state");
    return clearGrid()
})

const [interval, setInterval] = useState(50);
const intervalRef = useRef(interval);
intervalRef.current=(interval*10);

const [running, setRunning] = useState(false)

const runningRef = useRef(running)
runningRef.current = running;

const randomiseGrid = () => {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        rows.push(Array.from(Array(numCols), () => Math.random() > 0.9 ? 1 : 0))
    }
    setGrid(rows);
}

const runSimulation = useCallback(() => {
    if (!runningRef.current) {
        return;
    }

    setGrid((g) => {
        return produce(g, gridCopy => {
            for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < numCols; k++) {
                    let neighbours = 0;

                    operations.forEach(([x,y]) => {
                        const newI = i + x;
                        const newK = k + y;

                        // check if out of bounds
                        if (newI >= 0 && newI < numRows && newK >= 0 && newK < numCols) {
                            neighbours += g[newI][newK]
                        }
                    })

                    // apply rules
                    if (neighbours < 2 || neighbours > 3) {
                        gridCopy[i][k] = 0;
                    } else if (g[i][k] === 0 && neighbours === 3) {
                        gridCopy[i][k] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    })

    setTimeout(runSimulation, intervalRef.current)
},[numCols, numRows])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("grid: ",grid)
},[])

return (
    <>
    <div className="flex flex-col w-screen h-screen bg-white">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-end h-16 bg-white px-11">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-bold tracking-tight text-right text-black uppercase w-72">george conway's game of life</div>
        </div>
        <main className="flex flex-row w-full h-full p-11">
            <div
                className="w-full h-full bg-gray-100 rounded gridcontainer"
                style={{display: "grid",gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numCols}, 20px)`}}
            >
                {grid.map((rows, i) => rows.map((col, k) =>
                    <div
                        key={`${i}-${k}`}
                        onClick={() => {
                            const newGrid = produce(grid, gridCopy => {
                                gridCopy[i][k] = grid[i][k] ? 0 : 1;
                            })
                            setGrid(newGrid)
                        }}
                        className={`w-5 h-5 border border-gray-300 ${grid[i][k] ? 'bg-black' : undefined}`}/>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center h-full space-y-12 w-72 ml-11">
                <div>
                    <h3 className="text-sm text-center text-gray-700 uppercase">rules (how things evolve)</h3>
                    <ul className="flex flex-col mt-4 space-y-4">
                        <li className="text-sm font-light text-center text-gray-600">Any live cell with fewer than two or more than three live neighbours dies</li>
                        <li className="text-sm font-light text-center text-gray-600">Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {setRunning(!running)
                        if (!running) {
                            runningRef.current = true;
                            runSimulation();
                        }
                    }}
                    className="flex items-center justify-center w-48 h-12 font-medium text-white bg-gray-500 rounded focus:outline-none">
                        {running ? 'stop' : 'evolve'}
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={randomiseGrid}
                    className="flex items-center justify-center w-48 h-12 font-medium text-white bg-gray-500 rounded focus:outline-none">
                        randomise
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {setGrid(clearGrid())}}
                    className="flex items-center justify-center w-48 h-12 font-medium text-white bg-gray-500 rounded focus:outline-none">
                        clear
                </button>
                <div className="w-72">
                    <div className="mb-10 text-sm font-light text-center text-gray-600 uppercase">set interval</div>
                    <Slider
                        min={1}
                        max={100}
                        step={1}
                        color="gray"
                        defaultValue={50}
                        labelAlwaysOn
                        value={interval}
                        onChange={setInterval}
                    />
                </div>
                <p className="text-sm font-light text-center text-gray-600">
                    The Game of Life is a cellular automaton devised by Dr John Conway in 1970. The game is a zero-player game, meaning that its evolution is determined by its initial state. One interacts with the Game of Life by creating an initial configuration and observing how it evolves.
                </p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    </>
);
}
```

Any help very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's what happens if I initialise grid state in an onMount useEffect:

[image: UseEffect Error]

Comment: What is `document.readyState === 'complete'` use for? Why didn't use the React Hook useEffect with empty dependencies?

Comment: Because I get this warning with useEffect: "Assignments to the 'width' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render..."

Comment: Seems you should initialize your `grid` state in a mounting (*i.e. empty dependency*) `useEffect` hook. I also don't see where you conditionally call any React hooks for that warning/error to occur.

Comment: Hi Drew, I've added an image to my post.

Comment: Why are you trying to declare your state in the `useEffect` hook? This won't work and you can't do this as it breaks the rules of hooks. We're saying to ***set the state*** from the `useEffect` hook, not declare it.

Comment: Something like `useEffect(() => setGrid(clearGrid()), []);`. And for good measure, `width`, `height`, `numRows`, and `numCols` should probably be moved into local state or at least into a React ref so they are persisted through renders.

Comment: You should never (need to) use `document.querySelector` and friends with React (if you're the one rendering that element). Instead, you'd have a ref to the div you rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Drew said, you cannot use hooks in your useEffect (all hooks must be called on every render)

The problem in your code is you initialize `grid` with `clearGrid()` on the first render. but `numRows` used in that function still undefined.

you can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) and useEffect to initalize your grid

```
const [grid, setGrid] = useState();
const gridcontainer = useRef(null);

width = gridcontainer.current?.offsetWidth // consider that might be undefined
height = gridcontainer.current?.offsetHeight
let useableCols = (width / gridSize);
let useableRows = (height / gridSize);
numRows = Math.round(useableRows);
numCols = Math.round(useableCols);

const clearGrid = () => {/*...*/}

useEffect(()={
    if(gridcontainer.current){
        // gridcontainer is loaded
        setGrid(clearGrid())
    }
}, [gridcontainer.current])
return (
    [...]
    <div
        ref={gridcontainer} // pass the reference to useRef
        className="w-full h-full bg-gray-100 rounded gridcontainer"
        style={{display: "grid",gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numCols}, 20px)`}}
    >
    [...]
)
```

Comment: Superb Antonin! I don't know how you worked that out but you did! It works perfectly now. Thank you so much. You can see it working here: https://game-of-life-sage.vercel.app/